# Why is my implementation of a map on a custom type not correct?

Tags: haskell

I'm following the List exercise from https://github.com/NICTA/course

The below snippet copied from part of https://github.com/NICTA/course/blob/master/src/Course/List.hs

```
data List t =
  Nil
  | t :. List t
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

map ::
  (a -> b)
  -> List a
  -> List b
map f a = filter (\listElement -> listElement /= Nil) a
```

The above gives me the below error:
Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘List t0’ ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for map :: (a -> b) -> List a -> List b

I'm trying to achieve the below:

```
>>> map (+10) (1 :. 2 :. 3 :. Nil)
[11,12,13]
```

Comment: Your implementation of `map` looks really strange, since you are ignoring `f`.

Comment: Is `filter` defined on your custom list? Can you please post it too?

Comment: Apologies I rushed the question, I'm still intending to 'apply' f. But even if I don't apply f, I still don't understand why I get the error.

I haven't defined filter on my custom list.

If I don't use a parameter - would this cause errors? (Even if bad practice - still in the learning phase)

Comment: Actually filter was implemented but not directly by myself! I was working on the exercise from https://github.com/NICTA/course apologies.

Comment: Even if you implemented `filter` for your list, implementing `map` in terms of `filter` does not make sense. `filter` does not allow to return a different type of list, which `map` supports.

Comment: I do agree with you. It just so happens to be the way the exercise I was doing was written (which wanted an implementation of 'map' that would achieve what I stated above.

Answer (score 5):

First, to explain the error message: you can't use `filter` in your definition, since

```
 filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

has to do with regular Prelude lists, not your `List`s -- i.e. `[a]` not `List a`. The error message arises because `filter` expects `a` in

```
 map f a = filter (\listElement -> listElement /= Nil) a
```

to be a list of something, but the signature you supplied declares that `a` is a `List` of something. Similarly `filter` returns a Prelude list of something, but the signature requires that it return a `List` of something.

The natural implementation of `map` for `List` would distinguish the cases of `List` that you gave in the type declaration, that is, it would "pattern match":

```
mapList ::
    (a -> b)
    -> List a
    -> List b
mapList f Nil = Nil
mapList f (t :. ls) = f t :. mapList f ls
```

Note that the program you wrote is perfectly valid, it just conflicts with the signature you gave it:

```
ghci> let mapX f a = filter (\listElement -> listElement /= Nil) a
ghci> :t mapX
mapX :: Eq a => t -> [List a] -> [List a]
```

The `Eq` constraint is required because you presuppose that `List`s be tested for equality and thus that their elements can be.  `f` is not used, so it just ends up as a 'could be anything' parameter, here `t`.

Of course, if you have your own `filterList` for `List`s it will also typecheck

```
ghci> let filterList pred Nil = Nil; filterList pred (a :. as) = if pred a then a :. filterList pred as else filterList pred as

ghci> :t filterList
filterList :: (t -> Bool) -> List t -> List t

ghci> let mapY f a = filterList (\listElement -> listElement /= Nil) a

ghci> :t mapY
mapY :: Eq a => t -> List (List a) -> List (List a)
```

What this function does is delete null elements from a List of Lists, like `Prelude.filter (not . Prelude.null)`. Similarly, the actual function you defined (without the signature) deleted `Nil` Lists from a *Prelude list* of your Lists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I would accept it but I don't want to mislead anyone. (see my comments in my question). Essentially there was an implementation of 'filter' for the custom List type defined.

Comment: I added a bit about a dedicated `filterList` fwiw

Answer (score 1):

```
filter (\listElement -> listElement /= Nil) a
```

Here's the source of type error. If your implementation of `filter` follows reasonable path, `listElement` should be an element of `a`, that is, since `a` has type `List a`, it is of type `a`. You compare it for inequality against `Nil` which is of type `List a`.